# What does this notation in the definition of Weil divisors mean?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, definition

In the internet I have found the following definition of a Weil divisor and I am a bit confused about the definition:

> For $(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ a noetherian scheme the group of Weil divisors on $X$ is $\Bbb{Z}^{(X^1)}$ where $ X^1:\{C\subset X: C~\text{closed irreducible subset of codimension 1}\}$. More precisely a Weil divisor is a formal sum $$\sum_{C\in X^1} n_C [C]$$ where $|\{n_C\neq 0: C\in X^1\}|<\infty$.

Could someone explain me what they mean by $[C]$? So I think $n_c$ are integers but I don't get what this definition means by $[C]$.

Comment: This is the generator of the group corresponding to $C$.

Comment: @Sasha Sorry could you define this a bit more?

Comment: "formal sum" means you write the symbol and allow to sum it without ascribing it any numerical value. "chair + bicycle" is a formal sum. C is a closed irreducible subset of codimension 1 and $[C]$ is the symbol that I take a sum of. I am allowed to sum finitely many such closed subset symbols, with integer coefficients.

Comment: @ziggurism aha so can one say $[C]=\{x\in X: x\in C\}$? So in other words $[C]$ is considered as it's underlying set?

Comment: No $[C]$ is just a formal symbol used for writing sums. It is not a set containing the points of the codimension 1 closed subset $C$

Comment: @ziggurism but I should be able to sum over this sets $C$ so I should then need to know what it mans no?

Comment: It's a formal sum. $[C]$ has no numerical value, it is just a formal symbol, and you can't evaluate a sum like $[C]+[C']$ any further if $C\neq C'$. Just like you cannot evaluate "chair + bicycle". The phrase "formal sum" specifically means that the sum doesn't "mean" anything. All you can do is combine like terms if they correspond to the same $C$

Comment: Ahh okey so it is like when we take a formal power series $\sum_i a_i X^i$ there we also cannot think about $X$ to be a variable but an arbitrary value @ziggurism

Comment: Yes, it is just like a formal power series. The $X$ has no numerical value, it is just a formal bookkeeping symbol to keep track of like terms and powers and show you which like terms can be combined. The formal sum in a divisor is the same.

Comment: @ziggurism perfect thanks a lot!!

Comment: And the "free abelian group" mentioned by David Lui is the mathematical construction for making formal sums, so that answer is saying the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The free abelian group on a set $S$ is the set of functions $f : S \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ such that $f(x) \neq 0$ for only finitely many $x \in S$. It's an abelian group under pointwise addition. The symbol $[C]$ is the function $f(s) = \begin{cases} 1 \text { if $s= C$ } \\ 0 \text{ otherwise}\end{cases}$.

Then,  $\sum_i n_i [C_i]$ is just a sum of those functions.